# Android: TRying to show text saying sending when HttpClient sends message to server

Tags: android

I have a simple program that aks questions then call a php file saying if the answer was  a yes or a no.

Right now it works but there is a slight pause when the information is being send.  I would like some kind message or indicator to come up showing the computer is busy.

Now when I chnage the text of a textvue, before I send the data, the textView does not change, I allso tried to call it's update methed

code

```
case R.id.butYes:
                mSend .setText("Sending your vote to server");
                mSend.invalidate();
                 TalkToServer( mYes[mPes-1] );
                UpdateScreen(); 
                mSend .setText("");
                break;

       String TalkToServer( String addr)
       {   
           HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
           HttpPost  httppost = new HttpPost(addr);

            HttpResponse response;
            String responseBody=new String("");
            try {
                response = httpclient.execute(httppost);



responseBody = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());
            } catch (ParseException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

           return responseBody;
       }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) to avoid hanging of UI when sending data to server just change your code as:

```
case R.id.butYes:
  new SendTextOperation().execute("");  
  break;

private class SendTextOperation extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

      @Override
      protected void onPreExecute() {

        //Update UI here
        mSend.setText("Sending your vote to server");
        mSend.invalidate();
      }

      @Override
      protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            // Talk to server here to avoid Ui hanging 
            TalkToServer( mYes[mPes-1] );
            return null;
      }      

      @Override
      protected void onPostExecute(String result) {  
            // Update screen here after talk to server end
                UpdateScreen(); 
                mSend .setText("");
      }

}
```